# How to calculate the single value decomposition. when eigenvalue=0?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, svd

After calculating the eigenvalues. I got 0 as one of my 2 eigenvalues. Hence, one of the singular values of my matrix is 0.
So 
$\sigma_1 = 0$

But then when Im trying to find U:
 $$u_1 = \frac{1}{\sigma_1} Av_1$$

What do I do? $\frac{1}{\lambda_1} $ is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

The correct form of this equation (since we can't divide by $\sigma_1$) is 
$$
\sigma_1 u_1 = Av_1
$$
Since $\sigma_1=0$, we are free to select $u_1$. Keep in mind, however, that $u_1$ must be chosen to be length $1$, and orthogonal to all other $u_k$.

So, what you do is as follows: first, find all the other vectors $u_k$. Then, select *any* vectors for $\sigma=0$ such that, all together, the $u_k$ form an orthonormal basis.

You may want to use Gram Schmidt in order to do this.